# jQuery draggable clone size while dragging

Tags: jquery, resize, clone, draggable

I'm developping a drag-and-drop application. I have a droppable container and draggable.

```
$( "#dragshock" ).draggable( 
    {
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: 'move',
        drag: resizeContainer
    }
);
```

The function called by drag is this one:

```
function resizeContainer(e, ui) {
    var defaultSize = 108;
    var factor = ((ui.position.top)/19);
    var correcteSize = defaultSize + factor;
    $(this).width(correcteSize);
}
```

The function on the droppable container is this one:

```
$("#selectedpicture").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var $canvas = $(this);
        if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element')) {
            var $canvasElement = ui.draggable.clone();
            $canvasElement.addClass('canvas-element');
            $canvasElement.draggable({
                containment: '#geselecteerdefoto'
            });
            $canvas.append($canvasElement);
            var defaultSize = 108;formaat
            var factor = ((ui.position.top)/19);
            var correcteSize = defaultSize + factor;
            var imgSize = correcteSize;

            $canvasElement.css({
                left: (ui.position.left),
                top: (ui.position.top),
                width: imgSize,
                position: 'absolute'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

At the moment, the "drag: resizeContainer" line inside the draggable results in the dragged container to resize while dragging, instead of the clone which follows the mouse pointer.

What I want to achieve though, is WHILE dragging, the object allready visually resizes when dragging down inside the container. When dropped, that resize should be held.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7zkpc6s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was easier then I thought.

Replace the $(this).width(correcteSize) line inside resizeContainer with

```
$(ui.helper).width(correcteSize);
```

I updated the fiddle to the correct one for future references.